# Rewrite friendly URL not work by click on link

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to rewrite my website URL to more friendly URL, for example:

> www.mysite.com/profile.php

to

> www.mysite.com/profile

so far I'm able to do it by writing the rewrite URL in the URL address bar, but when go to the page by click on the link, the profile page URL doesn't change to rewrite URL. Am I missing something here?

this is my .htaccess codes

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteRule    ^profile/?$    profile.php    [NC,L]   # Handle requests for "profile"
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Try without that slash and question mark: `^profile$ profile.php` http://codingforliving.blogspot.com/2011/03/simple-url-rewriting-using-apache.html#mw2 And find out what that [NC,L] stands for. Somehow, I don't like it :-)

Comment: @DjuroMandinic really bad suggestion...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the URL of profile..

```
<a href="http://www.mysite.com/profile">Profile</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

`mod_rewrite` will not change URLs in your code. You have to do it.

If you can't or don't want to, you can use `RewriteRule` with `R` option to map from old to new URL.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't change because your rule only internally rewrites `profile` to `profile.php`, you need a different rule to do it the other way, and externally so the browser gets redirected:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /profile\.php
RewriteRule ^ /profile [L,R]
```